# I only want only name and tag, but now I am getting model also as you can see in output

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to connect my node with my mongodb.i have no issue in that. Here i am getting my value as well as model in output, but I only like to have my name and tag in terminal, so is there a way.

i am doing it in window OS. so is it an window setting issue. so please let me know what is the way to get tags and name.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/playground')
    .then(()=>console.log('Connected to MongoDB...'))
    .catch(err =>console.error('Could not connect to MongoDB...',err));

const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : String,
    author : String,
    tags : [String],
    date : {type : Date, default : Date.now},
    isPublished : Boolean
});

const Course = mongoose.model('Course',courseSchema);

async function createCourse(){
    const course = new Course({
        name : 'Angular.js Course',
        author: 'Mosh',
        tags : ['Angular','Frontend'],
        isPublished : true
    });
    const result = await course.save();
    // console.log(result);
}

async function getCourses(){
    const courses = await Course
        .find({ author: 'Kunal', isPublished : true})
        .limit(10)
        .sort({name : 1})
        .select({name : 1, tags : 1});
     console.log(courses);
}

getCourses();
```

output

```
Connected to MongoDB...
[
  model {
    '$__': InternalCache {
      strictMode: true,
      selected: [Object],
      shardval: undefined,
      saveError: undefined,
      validationError: undefined,
      adhocPaths: undefined,
      removing: undefined,
      inserting: undefined,
      version: undefined,
      getters: {},
      _id: 5fc6f9ba8059e13514a7de87,
      populate: undefined,
      populated: undefined,
      wasPopulated: false,
      scope: undefined,
      activePaths: [StateMachine],
      pathsToScopes: {},
      ownerDocument: undefined,
      fullPath: undefined,
      emitter: [EventEmitter],
      '$options': true
    },
    isNew: false,
    errors: undefined,
    _doc: {
      tags: [Array],
      _id: 5fc6f9ba8059e13514a7de87,
      name: 'node.js Course'
    },
    '$init': true
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need to add .lean() to achieve what you want :

```
async function getCourses(){
    const courses = await Course
        .find({ author: 'Kunal', isPublished : true})
        .limit(10)
        .sort({name : 1})
        .select({name : 1, tags : 1}).lean();

     console.log(courses);
}
```

> The lean() function tells mongoose to not hydrate query results. In
> other words, the results of your queries will be the same plain
> JavaScript objects that you would get from using the Node. js MongoDB
> driver directly, with none of the mongoose magic.